# Lightning-record-picker component error when adding a variable name to its filter criteria

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am trying out the new `lightning-record-picker` component and it went well until I added a variable to the filter criteria.
Here is my HTML -

```
<lightning-record-picker
    label="Parts Family"
    placeholder="Select Part Family"
    object-api-name="Product2"
    matching-info={matchingInfo}
    display-info={displayInfo}
    filter={filter}
    onchange={handleRecordPickerChange}
></lightning-record-picker>
```

Here is my JS. In the below example, the issue is when I set the value attribute of the filter criteria to a variable. Is there another way I should be doing this?

```
export default class CreateWorkOrderLWCComponent extends LightningElement {
    @api caseId;
    @api veteranEquipmentType;
    isPartSelected = false;
    showDatatable = false;

    selectedPartId;
    selectedPartName;
    @track selectedPartIssue;

    @track selectedParts = [];

    matchingInfo = {
        primarrField: { fieldPath: "Name" },
        additionalFields: [{ fieldPath: "Family" }],
    };
    displayInfo = {
        additionalFields: ["Family"]
    }

    filter = {
        criteria: [
            {
                fieldPath: 'Family',
                operator: 'eq',
                value: this.veteranEquipmentType,
            },
            {
                fieldPath: 'IsActive',
                operator: 'eq',
                value: true,
            },
        ],
    }



    handleRecordPickerChange(event) {
        this.selectedPartId = event.detail.recordId;
        this.isPartSelected = this.selectedPartId != null ? true : false;
    }

    
}
```

When I add it to a variable I get the below component error -
[image]

Comment: When I tried as `type = 'Personal';
    filter = {
        criteria: [
            {
                fieldPath: 'Family',
                operator: 'eq',
                value: this.type,
            },
        ],
    }`
It is worked.

Comment: Also can you please check that the `@api type;` variable has value? You can also set the default value to the type.

Comment: @Tushar I checked the api type does have value in it. I have added a screenshot with the error.

Comment: If possible can you please share the full code?

Comment: @TusharJadav full code added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Js file, Initialize the `filter` variable with blank. After that in the `connectedCallback` assign the filters as I mention below.

HTML::

```
<template>
        <div class="slds-grid">
                <div class="slds-col slds-size_9-of-12">
                        <div class="slds-grid slds-grid_vertical">
                                <div class="slds-col">
                                        <span><lightning-record-picker variant="label-hidden" label="Parts Family"
                            placeholder="Select a part" object-api-name="Product2" matching-info={matchingInfo}
                            display-info={displayInfo} filter={filter}
                            onchange={handleRecordPickerChange}></lightning-record-picker></lightning-button></span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="slds-col">
                                        <span><lightning-textarea label="Describe the issue:" placeholder="Describe the issue..."
                            variant="label-hidden"></lightning-textarea></lightning-button></span>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slds-col slds-size_3-of-12 ">
                        <span class="slds-var-p-around_medium slds-grid_align-center">
                                <lightning-button class="my-button slds-float_right" 
                    variant="brand" label="Add Part" onclick={handleClick}>
                                        </lightning-button>
                                        </span>
                </div>
        </div>
</template>
```

JS::

```
import { LightningElement, api, track } from 'lwc';
import { loadStyle } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import customStyles from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/myBtnCSS';

export default class TestComponent extends LightningElement {
        
    @api caseId;
    @api veteranEquipmentType;
    isPartSelected = false;
    showDatatable = false;

    selectedPartId;
    selectedPartName;
    @track selectedPartIssue;

    @track selectedParts = [];

    matchingInfo = {
        primarrField: { fieldPath: "Name" },
        additionalFields: [{ fieldPath: "Family" }],
    };
    displayInfo = {
        additionalFields: ["Family"]
    }

    filter = {};    

    connectedCallback() {
         loadStyle(this, customStyles).then(() => {
            console.log('css loaded');
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log('error to load');
        });
        console.log('this.veteranEquipmentType :: ' + this.veteranEquipmentType);
        this.filter = {
            criteria: [
                {
                    fieldPath: 'Family',
                    operator: 'eq',
                    value: this.veteranEquipmentType,
                },
                {
                    fieldPath: 'IsActive',
                    operator: 'eq',
                    value: true,
                },
            ],
        };
    }

    handleRecordPickerChange(event) {
        this.selectedPartId = event.detail.recordId;
        this.isPartSelected = this.selectedPartId != null ? true : false;
    } 

    handleClick(event){

    }   
}
```

CSS::

```
lightning-button.my-button {
    height: 100%;
}
```

myBtnCSS.css as Static Resource::

```
.my-button > button {
    height: -webkit-fill-available !important;
}
```

Output::
[image]
[image]

Comment: Sorry, I am still having the same error. When I use a variable I get the component load error.

Comment: @sumchans, I have edited my answer and added full code which worked well.

Comment: Thanks Tushar. Your answer worked.